# Return data once its been fetched JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

Using nodeJS.

I have a main file that calls a web scraper that goes out to a few links and gets raw data from the sites and then the next line calls a function from the web scraper file that returns a JSON object to the main file. But because it takes a little while to go out and scrape the websites the return is returning an empty object. How do you use callbacks or other methods to wait for the data before calling the get method.

main file

```
var test = require('web-scraper.js');

test.scrape(next);

function next()
{
    var json = test.getJSON();
}
```

web-scraper.js (It uses module exports and is in the node modules folder)

```
module.exports = 
{
    scrape: function(callback)
    {
        startScraper(callback);
    },

    getJSON: function()
    {
        return JSON;
    }
};

function startScraper(callback)
{
    // Does web scraper stuff

    callback();
}
```

Comment: the web-scraper package is undocumented on npm, the git page is not valid, so you'll need to look through the source code to see how to use it - or use [scraperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scraperjs) which is documented

Comment: Of course, I assumed the web-scraper was the one on npm - which I see now was wrong - you'll need to handle the asynchronicity somehow, without seeing any code for `startScraper` (your code?) only you know how that can be done

Comment: Sorry, yes web-scraper.js is my own file. The webscraper goes and gets data and saves it in a json object 'JSON' i was wondering how to use callbacks poosibly so when start is finished have a callback that calls a function that has a getJSON() call in it. But i cant seem to use a callback from the web-scraper.js file to the main file

Comment: `But i cant seem to use a callback from the web-scraper.js file to the main file` - well, you've shown no attempt to do so, so how can anyone say why you can't perform such a fundamental and basic task that nodejs is basically built on

Comment: Sorry have i done something wrong? I edited the question to include the callback I tried.

Comment: The callback looks good to me, maybe the problem is in the scraper stuff part. It's possible it's making asynchronous operations which you are not waiting for.

Comment: Think I found the problem, the startScraper function pops a url from an array and calls a function passing the url to it, the function does the scraping then calls back to startScraper, it does this until the array is empty, because the last thing to call startScraper was a callback to it, i have 'lost' the initial callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript callback or promises to wait till fetch is completed. Read following article how to do simple http call. It described callback

https://www.google.lk/amp/s/davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request/amp?client=ms-android-xiaomi

Read following post to understand how to use promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise